"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'OverviewCard')" in Flutter project
Almost every time I run my project in debug mode in VS Code, I get this error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'OverviewCard') (OverviewCard is a custom widget I created). The widget mentioned after the "reading" part is almost always random — sometimes it even blames MaterialApp.
There's nothing wrong with my code, as it occasionally runs perfectly fine. But the moment I close the application and rerun it, the error comes back. I've tried all the usual fixes - restarting VS Code, restarting the project, running flutter clean, and flutter pub get. Sometimes, one of these options works, but mostly it just changes the widget after the "reading" part in the error.
I suspect it might have something to do with how Flutter is set up on my Linux system, but I haven't been able to figure it out yet.
I've attached an image of the error:


This question https://stackoverflow.com/q/75625031/12507984 seems to be dealing with the same issue.
